# View with more than one button redirecting to different pages

Tags: python, django, view

I have a View (I use `FormView`) that will render a dropdown option. When I select an option, an Ajax function populate the rest of the Form. After the datas are shown, the user can press different buttons to redirect to other pages. For now, I want just 2 buttons. But I don't know how to do this, I've tried some codes and got nothing, not even got redirect to other page. The first page are "Teste" and the buttons need to redirect to "identificacao", or "mapa". Here are my following code

urls.py:

```
path('teste', views.TesteView.as_view(), name="teste"),
path('identificacao', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'solid/identificacao.html'), name="identificacao"),
path('mapa', views.MapaView.as_view(), name="mapa")
```

view.py:

```
class DutosView(generic.FormView):
    # FormView precisa ser relacionada a um Model. Mesmo que não use ao longo do 
    # programa a variável "model", como é o caso presente.    
    template_name = 'solid/teste.html'
    form_class = Teste
    # success_url = 'solid/mapa.html'
    # success_url = reverse_lazy('mapa')
    success_url = '/mapa/'

    def form_valid(self, form):        
        nomeDuto = form.cleaned_data['nomeDuto']
        codigoDuto = DUTO.objects.values_list('DU_CD_ID_Duto',flat = True).filter(DU_DS_Nome_Do_Duto = nomeDuto)

        self.request.session['nomeDuto'] = nomeDuto
        latlongs = PIG.objects.values_list("PI_VL_Latitude","PI_VL_Longitude").filter(PI_CD_ID_Duto = codigoDuto)
        latlongs = [[float(x[0]),float(x[1])] for x in latlongs]
        latitudeIni = latlongs[0][0]
        longIni = latlongs[0][1]
        self.request.session['latlongs'] = latlongs
        self.request.session['latitudeIni'] = latitudeIni
        self.request.session['longIni'] = longIni                      
        return super().form_valid(form)
        # I've tried the code above to redirect when I click on the button and didn't work.
        # But, even the super().form_valid isn't redirecting to succes_url.
        #if 'Mapa' in self.request.POST:
        #   redirect('mapa')
        #if 'Confirmar' in self.request.POST:
        # I've thought to assign a new value do success_url here to "identificacao".
        #   redirect('identificacao')
```

teste.html:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="testeForm" data-nome-teste-url="{% url 'ajax_load_nome_teste' %}" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
          <table id = "formTable">
            <h3>Selecione um Nome:</h1>
              <br>
              <div class="fieldWrapper">
                  {{ form.nomeTeste.errors }}
                  <label for="nomeTeste"> Nome: </label>
                  {{ form.nomeTeste }}
              </div>
              <br>
              <div id="id_campos"> 

              </div>            
          </table>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Confirmar">
          <input type="submit" value="Mapa" name="mapa">
      </div>
      </form>
```

In `id_campo`, I put a python function to render the rest of the form with the selection of `nomeTeste`. These fields are from the Database and will have some function later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name and value of the submit input clicked will be passed in the POST data

```
<input type="submit" value="Button 1" name="button_1">
<input type="submit" value="Button 2" name="button_2">
```

Then in your view you can look for the name of the submit. I would suggest putting this logic in the [`get_success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url) method

```
def get_success_url(self):
    if 'button_1' in self.request.POST:
        return redirect('url_for_button_1')
    elif 'button_2' in self.request.POST:
        return redirect('url_for_button_2')
    # etc
```

Comment: The part that I get the values of the form (like I do in `form_valid`) and pass to the session I put in the `get_sucess_url`? The documentation says `form_valid` redirect to `get_sucess_url`, but I still have this doubt.

Comment: I've tried to run it with debug, clicked one of the buttons and the `form_valid` wasn't triggered by the debug, and not even the `get_success_url`.

Comment: I changed the forms.py  for this view. I have other fields that I was not using, now it is going through `form_valid` and `get_success_url`. I'm fixing bugs now.